# Checking each of element in 2D matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have `100x100` `matrix` in `numpy` which is made of `0's` and `1's`. I also have a `canvas` made of squares which are arranged `100x100`. This `canvas` is in correspondence with `matrix` (first square to `element[0,0]`, second to `[1,0]...` it goes row by row from left to right). I have to check each element from the `matrix` and if it's `0` the square has to be `white` and if it is `1` the square has to be `black`. I've tried some methods but none of them works. How can I check each elements of the matrix so I can decide if the color is black or white?

```
a=0
b=0
m=np.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\preklopenie_obrazka.txt", 
skiprows=1 )
for n in range(0,99):
    if m[a][b]==0.0:
        f='white'
    else:
        f='black'
    a+=1
    b+=1
```

Comment: you should use two loops to access all elements in 2D matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout [iamchoosinganame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10620028/iamchoosinganame)'s answer, which is concise and uses `numpy`'s awesome capabilities.

I'm leaving my answer here just for the sake of showing how to correctly loop, based on your code:

your code is mistakenly only checking the main diagonal of the matrix.

think about it: after you're done with `a=1` and `b=1`, you increment both, so next iteration is `a=2` and `b=2`, then `a=3` and `b=3`... etc.

also - `range` is not inclusive on the end, so you want range(0,100) to get all the numbers up to 99

you want to use `for` twice (also, you don't have to increment the loop variable yourself):

```py
m=np.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\preklopenie_obrazka.txt", skiprows=1 )
for a in range(0,100):
    for b in range(0,100):
        if m[a][b]==0.0:
            f='white'
        else:
            f='black'
        print(f)  # CHANGE: just use f in whatever way you need
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop

```
# create the canvas as a copy of the original matrix
canvas=m.copy()
# convert canvas to have 'object' type so it can contain different types
canvas=canvas.astype('object')
#replace the values with the colors
canvas[canvas==0]='white'
canvas[canvas==1]='black'
```

canvas will now be a numpy array with white for all elements of m equal to 0 and black for all elements equal to 1.

Comment: Use `np.where(m, 'black', 'white')`